# html5 manifest caching error

Tags: html, manifest

I am creating a html5 web app. In that web app Contents are loaded dynamically from the XML feed. The feed XML has list of image URLs. I added that URLs in the cache.manifest file to support offline access. In that list of URLs if one URL is giving 404, because of that caching is not working how to solve this issue.

Comment: Put the missing image where you say it should be or stop saying it should be where it isn't.

Comment: putting the missing image is fine.In the manifest file looks like below     # Add the images in to the cache
/webapp/icon.png
/webapp/startup.png
/webapp/draft/bg_pattern.png                                  /webapp/draft/close.png
if the close button is not there in the path whole caching is not working. but the other images are there in the path.because of one image url 404 whole offline mechanisam should not fail. how to solve this.

Comment: Please note that code pasted into comment boxes is unreadable; use the [edit] link to improve your question. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem While Doing html5 webapp cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677813/problem-while-doing-html5-webapp-cache)

Comment: Please consider this question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manifest cache files will fail (and therefore your appcache will be incomplete) if there are *any* errors at all. So, if the `close.png` URL is throwing a 404, remove it or correct it—your cache won't work otherwise, simple as that.