# Problem While Doing html5 webapp cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, manifest, manifest.cache

I have a webapp which has the domain http://draft.mo2do.com

when i am accessing the url it will resolve like the below url and redirect to the corresponding site home page

http://draft.mo2do.com/s/_91665/Home

Here i implemented offline cache. My cache.manifest file is the below

```
   CACHE MANIFEST
   # Offline cache v4.0

   # All other resources (e.g. sites) require the user to be online.  

   NETWORK:

   *

   # Additional resources to cache CACHE:

   # Add the pages in to the cache 

   /s/_91665/Home /s/_91665/CachedDraftBoard

   http://draft.mo2do.com

   # Add the images in to the cache 

   /s/store/-1/webapp/styles/webapp.css

   /s/store/-1/webapp/styles/nba_draft.css

   /s/store/-1/webapp/styles/add2drafthome.css?v2  

   #  Add the js files in to the cache 

   /s/store/-1/webapp/scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js

   /s/store/-1/webapp/scripts/iscroll.js

   /s/store/-1/webapp/scripts/webapp.js

   /s/store/-1/webapp/scripts/nba_draft.js

   /s/store/-1/webapp/scripts/cacheUpdate.js

   /s/store/-1/webapp/scripts/add2drafthome.js?v0.9.4  



   /webapp/icon.png /webapp/startup.png

   /s/store/-1/webapp/nba/addtodrafthome/arrow.png

   /s/store/-1/webapp/nba/addtodrafthome/close-bubble.png

   /s/store/-1/webapp/nba/addtodrafthome/icon.png

   /s/store/-1/webapp/nba/addtodrafthome/plus.png

   /s/store/-1/webapp/nba/addtodrafthome/share.png

   FALLBACK: 

   http://draft.mo2do.com
```

If i am directly accessing the site url the caching is working and that time i didnt mention the  "http://draft.mo2do.com" in the cache section.During this time offline cache is working fine.

If i directly access only the domain url "http://draft.mo2do.com" in the browser it is not opening 404 in the offline mode.

Then i added the "http://draft.mo2do.com" in the cache section that time i am getting exception

Application Cache Progress event (2 of 3) http://draft.mo2do.com/ Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (-1) http://draft.mo2do.com/

If i access the domain also it should load the app in the offline mode. If i access direct url app is loading fine.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The cache has to directly reference specific resources, be they Javascript, CSS, HTML pages, images, whatever. From what I can tell from the content above, you've done that. Simply placing a domain in there however won't work (you also need to reference *all* of the pages you want off-line, e.g. `/s/_91665/Home` needs to be in there).

So, there's an error somewhere along the line, but it's hard to figure out what you mean by this:

> If i directly access only the domain url "http://draft.mo2do.com" in the browser it is not opening 404 in the offline mode.

Can you be more clear? Do you mean that going to that URL results in a 404, or is there something in the page itself that's in error?

Are you sure that your cache file is functioning as intended? **If there are any errors at all in your cache file, your off-line application simply won't work**. This page offers some debugging code which may help:

[Debugging HTML 5 Offline Application Cache](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/)

Comment: It is local url.i will launch my webapp by typing the "http://draft.mo2do.com" in the browser. when i access that url it will redirect to http://draft.mo2do.com/s/_91665/Home this url and the cached page also i mentioned in the cache section. the home page url is getting cached so when i access the home page url in the offline mode it is loading.but the "http://draft.mo2do.com" urlis not getting cached that y i am getting 404. if i added that url in the cache section i am getting the resource fetch failed error. what i need is when i acess the domain url also it should load from offline cache.